# How to notify PropertyChanged after Image Opened?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am having some problems with my gallery. First I download all thumbnails for an overview. But when I click on a picture, first I want to show the thumbnail and load the big picture. When this is done, I want to change the ImageSource to the new picture. Here is my example:

```
    private BitmapImage picture;   
    public BitmapImage Picture
    {
        get
        {
            if (picture == null)
            {
                RequestBigpicture();
                return Thumbnail;
            }
            return picture;
        }
    }   

    public void RequestBigpicture()          
    {
        picture = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.fun-hollywood.de/" + bigPicture, UriKind.Absolute));
        picture.ImageOpened += pictureImage_ImageOpened;
    }

    void pictureImage_ImageOpened(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Picture");
    }
```

This was not working, also this part (as I read somewhere) in RequestBitPicture is not better:

```
        picture = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.fun-hollywood.de/" + bigPicture, UriKind.Absolute));
        var pictureImage = new Image();
        pictureImage.Source = picture;
        pictureImage.ImageOpened += pictureImage_ImageOpened;
```

The ImageOpened is never called. How would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set the [`BitmapImage.CreateOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property to `None` or to `BackgroundCreation` to instantly trigger the image download.
Because the default value is `DelayCreation` that is why your image won't donwloaded and the `ImageOpened` event is never fired.